# How do I paste a list of files to a command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, mac

Let's say I have a newline-separated list of file paths from a previous command that I can copy to clipboard. What's the easiest way to paste this list to feed it into another command in a shell? Preferably, so that I can still edit the list before executing the command. E.g., I want to `rm` some subset of the untracked files returned by `git status`.

Comment: I'm getting downvotes and no help... I guess this belongs on StackOverflow instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, the best answer I found is

```
cat | xargs rm
```

I didn't realize it, but after Ctrl-D, it will pipe it as expected to the target command.

Answer (score 1):

git has a command for deleting untracked files.

```
git clean --exclude=<pattern> --dry-run  # Remove --dry-run to delete for real
git clean  --interactive # Or, interactive mode is a prompt version
```

Or, a more general solution is to pipe delimited strings into  `xargs`, to batch run some command (`rm`) on the input.  Although, this requires that stdin only contains the list of files.  For git, this implies using plumbing commands designed to be parsed.   In practice, `git clean` is easier to use for this specific use case.

Comment: Good tip on the `git clean` parameters. But I was hoping for something more generic...

Comment: I mentioned a more generic way via `xargs`. A common pattern is to generate (new line) delimited strings on stdout, and pipe those into `xargs` to do a thing with every input. (No cut and paste needed.)  But I am not going to bother with generating that list myself with git "plumbing" commands, when a user friendly "porcelain" command to do the specific thing already exists.